# open visual studio 2008 through the location link in fxcop

Tags: visual-studio-2008, fxcop

I have created a class library in Visual Studio 2008. Now, I need to run the code analysis. I have used fxcop for this. I added that class library dll into the target and run the code analysis. When I go to the Analysis window and click on the target location link to open the that specified file, it's open that file in the visual studio 2005 instead of Visual Studio 2008. How can I set it to Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/vstscode/thread/c77ba3b3-b87e-4e8a-a562-75d74d720918